# Minimum number and interest does not print correctly

Tags: python

I am in a Python class and a few weeks ago we were given these sets of instructions for an assignment:

> Write a program that utilizes a loop to read a set of five floating-point
> values from user input. Ask the user to enter the values, then print the
> following data:
> Total,
> Average,
> Maximum,
> Minimum,
> Interest at 20% for each original value entered by the user.
> Use the formula: Interest_Value = Original_value + Original_value*0.2

I uploaded a different assignment for the class, but this problem is driving me crazy because I cannot figure out why minimum number, and interest does not work correctly. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

This is the code I wrote. My problem is the minimum number does not output and the printed interest is wrong.

```
entered_number = 0
sum = 0
average = 0
max_number = 0
min_number = 0
interest = 0.2

for entered_number in range(5):
    entered_number = float(input('Enter a number: '))
    
    if entered_number > max_number:
        max_number = entered_number
    if entered_number < min_number:
        min_number = entered_number 

sum = sum + entered_number
average = sum / 5
interest = entered_number + (entered_number * interest) # removing the () didn't solve

print('Total:', sum)
print('Average:', average)
print('Maximum number:', max_number)
print('Minimum number:', min_number)
print('Interest at 20% for each entered number is: ', interest)
```

My output example:

```
Enter a number: 20
Enter a number: 30
Enter a number: 40
Enter a number: 50
Enter a number: 60
Total: 200.0
Average: 40.0
Maximum number: 60.0
Minimum number: 0
Interest at 20% for each entered number is:  90123060.0
```

Comment: Well no number was smaller than 0 so `minimum_number` wasn't changed.

Comment: How did you end up with `interest = 90123060.0`?  Your exact code gives me 72, which is what I expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your `min_number` and `max_number` values to positive and negative infinity respectively, upon intialization.

Then for the interest it sounds like you need to collect multiple values and output all of them if I understand correctly. And you don't want to overwrite the `interest` variable because that is constant between all numbers so use `current_interest` and move it inside the loop.

For the total you shouldn't use `sum` as a variable name since it overwrites the function. instead use `total`, and move it inside the loop so that the value updates for each input received.

```
import math

entered_number = 0
total = 0
average = 0
max_number = -math.inf
min_number = math.inf
interest = 0.2

interest_list = []

for entered_number in range(5):
    entered_number = float(input('Enter a number: '))
    
    if entered_number > max_number:
        max_number = entered_number
    if entered_number < min_number:
        min_number = entered_number 

    current_interest = entered_number + (entered_number * interest)   
    interest_list.append(current_interest)  # collect all interest values
    total += entered_number    # dont use sum as a variable name

average = total / 5


print('Total:', total)
print('Average:', average)
print('Maximum number:', max_number)
print('Minimum number:', min_number)
print('Interest at 20% for each entered number is: ', interest_list)
```

OUTPUT

```
Enter a number: 20
Enter a number: 30
Enter a number: 40
Enter a number: 50
Enter a number: 60
Total: 200.0
Average: 40.0
Maximum number: 60.0
Minimum number: 20.0
Interest at 20% for each entered number is:  [24.0, 36.0, 48.0, 60.0, 72.0]
```